# sed how to show only largest number of line containing "Page"

Tags: sed

Currently, this shows only numbers.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')
```

How can I tell sed to display ONLY the largest number found, taking into account ONLY the line which contains the word "Page" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep Page filename | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

This assumes the page number is the 2nd word of the line (if not, change the awk command as appropriate)

Comment: What is awk '{print $2}' for? -- I had to change it to >> `$somefile | grep Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | sort -n | tail -n 1` because having sed first would remove non-numbers making it impossible for grep to find Page.

Comment: If you're using awk, don't need grep: `awk '/Page/ {print $2}' filename | ...`

Comment: @glenn jackman - thanks for the tip (I'm not a command line guru)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/Page/!d; s/[^0-9]//g' | sort -n | tail -1
```

or

```
awk '/Page/ {gsub(/[^0-9]/,""); if ($0 > max) max = $0} END {print max}'
```